# Evaluating an integral along a portion of the curve $x^2+y^2=4$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the integral $\int_{0,2}^{2,0}x^2ydy$ along C. With C being the portion of the curve $x^2+y^2=4$ lying in the first quadrant.

So far I have $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}$ suggesting the parametric representation C:$z=\sqrt{4-y^2}+iy(-2\le y\le2)$ 
however I feel as though I have already gone down the wrong track

This question has come from the Brown & Churchill 8th Edition of complex variables and applications. Unfortunately only the odd answers are provided.

Comment: Why not just substitute $x^2=4-y^2$ and get an integral depending only on $y$?

Comment: Could you explain that concept further for me?

Comment: He means substituting the $x^2$ in the integral $\int_{0,2}^{2,0}\color{magenta}{x^2}y\,\mathrm{d}y$ as $4-y^2$.

Comment: Thankyou, that helps! Following this procedure, my answer would be -4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0.2}^{2.0}x^2ydy=\int_{0.2}^{2.0}(4-y^2)ydy=\left[2y^2-\frac14 y^4\right]_{0.2}^{2.0}=2(2.0)^2-\frac14 (2.0)^4-2(0.2)^2+\frac14 (0.2)^4=3.9204$$
Correction after Bob Jones's comment :
$$\int_{(x=0,y=2)}^{(x=2,y=0)}x^2ydy=\int_{2}^{0}(4-y^2)ydy=\left[2y^2-\frac14 y^4\right]_{2}^{0}=2(0)^2-\frac14 (0)^4-2(2)^2+\frac14 (2)^4=-4$$

Comment: Those are commas, not decimal points. It goes from $y=2$ and $x=0$ to $y=0$ and $x=2$.

Comment: I didn't notice it. I will correct my answer.  Thank you for the remark.